# Pygame screen looping back

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, pygame

I am making a game in python, which has a main menu, followed by a difficulty select screen. When I select the play game button, the screen changes to the difficulty select screen as intended, but when I click a difficulty, it returns to the main menu screen, which is fully functional, leading me to believe that the function is continuing to run. If I then return to the difficulty select screen and select a difficulty a second time the game progresses as expected. No other button leads to this error which leads me to believe the error is in the select difficulty function itself.

```
def gameIntro(): # game intro loop
    playButton=classes.Button(100,200,275,350,selectDifficulty) #classes is external file which contains a button class. params (x,y,w,h,action=None)
    leaderButton=classes.Button(700,200,275,350,leaderboard)
    quitButton=classes.Button(1000,200,250,350,quit)
    instructButton=classes.Button(425,200,275,350,instructions)
    spriteGroup = pygame.sprite.Group(playButton, leaderButton, quitButton, instructButton)
    while not(playButton.loop and leaderButton.loop and quitButton.loop and instructButton.loop): #all of button objects have loop set to false, until they are clicked
        eventLoop(spriteGroup) #runs an event handler for all of objects in spriteGroup
        mainMenuScreen = pygame.image.load('Menu.jpg')  # loads the menu Screens
        mainMenuScreen = pygame.transform.scale(mainMenuScreen, (displayWidth, displayHeight)) #adjusts image to be same size as display
        gameDisplay.blit(mainMenuScreen, (0, 0)) #displays the image
        pygame.display.update() #updates the display
        clock.tick(fps) #increments the clock by the fps amount to keep the screen changing

def selectDifficulty(): #selects the difficulty so that the appropriate AI is loaded
    import Main
    easyButton=classes.Button(70,150,300,400,Main.easyAIMaker)
    mediumButton=classes.Button(450,150,300,400)
    hardButton=classes.Button(800,150,300,400)
    spriteGroup = pygame.sprite.Group(easyButton,mediumButton,hardButton)
    while not (easyButton.loop and mediumButton.loop and hardButton.loop): #loops the screen while a choice hasnt been made
        eventLoop(spriteGroup)
        difficultyScreen = pygame.image.load('difficulty screen.jpg')
        difficultyScreen = pygame.transform.scale(difficultyScreen, (displayWidth, displayHeight))
        gameDisplay.blit(difficultyScreen, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: please put space before `#` in comments in code and SO it will use different color for these comments and code will be more readable.

Comment: BTW: good rule: all `import` put at the beginning of script. This way everyone will know what other modules it needs to run correctly. See more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: for this problem is more important code which handle events, not code which display screens. Maybe you have wrong function assigned to button or button work in wrong way and when you click it then it show correct screen but then it automatically click back button which goes back to main menu - it is common problem in PyGame if it doesn't use `pygame.BUTTONDOWN` to check click but `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`

Comment: I placed imports in functions to avoid circular import errors. I am using .buttondown in my event handler. When I can I will post code for event handler

Comment: at start you can use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed when you press buttons. It may help to find where is the problem. It is called "print debugging".

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I didn't realise how python treated imported code. At the very end of intro.py the gameintro() function is called to start the game. When I imported intro.py this code was rerun causing the loop. By shielding game intro inside:

```
Def main():
    gameIntro()

If __name__=="__main__":
    Main()
```

The gameintro function only runs once